# File Storing Error in public directory (where index.php located)

Tags: laravel, makefile, storage, kinsta

I am facing an issue, i have a working code on my machine but when I make this live it's giving error which is as follows Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException: Unable to write in the "/app/public/media" directory. in file /app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php on line 131

here is the code that I am using to upload files

```
       if (!File::isDirectory($directory)) {
            File::makeDirectory($directory, 0755, true, true);
        }

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $fileName = time() . '_' . $this->cleanString($file->getClientOriginalName()); // You can customize the file name if needed
        $file->move(public_path('media'), $fileName);
```

This code is working fine in local machine, but not on live, I am using kinsta app for the laravel, I don't want to use the laravel storage directory but it's not working, can someone have a look

Further here is the video link (video time 2 minutes): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OU65PXYrZaL3pJkDcpAqXfHoy8emN38s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: is that the only error? did it say permission denied or something else?

Comment: Yes, currently i am getting this

Comment: Then it is permission issue. check google for this. There should be plenty of information about it.

Comment: `chmod -R 755 public`
`chmod -R 755 public/media`

I have run these commands, but stull it's not wirking

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following commands

```
chmod -R 777 public
```